# Finding expected value through a different RV

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

[image]

I am currently studying probability and statistics at second year university level and have came across this question. Previously I was not sure on how to approach this. I initially thought I needed to work out the ImY but now know that this is the right approach. Having now looked over the replies and course notes again, I realise that using the concept 'Expected value of g(x)' was the obvious approach and proceeding on with integrating the multiple of the two function with the boundaries 0 and +infinity. I apologise for not using the correct maths coding as I'm not quite sure how to use it yet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your random variable is a negative exponential

$$X\sim Exp(4)$$

the requested expectation is easy to calculate with the definition

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)f(x)dx$$

That in your case is

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-5X}]=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-5x}4e^{-4x}dx$$

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-5X}]=\frac{4}{9}\underbrace{\int_0^{+\infty}9e^{-9x}dx}_{=1}=\frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: So does this turn into the integral of 4e^(-9x)?

Comment: @Taylor : of course...I edited my answer with "all" the necessary passage.

Comment: Am I correct to say that the expected value is 4/9?

Comment: @Taylor : absolutely correct!